Vault not able to sync data - Using ecs and s3 as storage backend
I have a HashiCorp Vault deployed in Amazon ECS with two tasks running. The setup includes AWS S3 as a backend storage for Vault and AWS KMS for auto-unsealing, with an Application Load Balancer (ALB) in front.
I’m encountering the following issues:
Data Inconsistency:
When accessing Vault through the ALB, auto-unsealing works intermittently. Creating secrets succeeds, but retrieving them shows inconsistency. Sometimes secrets are displayed, while other times they are not until multiple attempts.
Data Persistence Issue:
Only after restarting all ECS tasks can I consistently access secrets in Vault. Restarting is not an option when it comes to production…
Why am I experiencing these behaviors despite using the same S3 backend? How can I ensure data persistence and resolve the inconsistency in secret retrieval?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have tried using s3 and backend as well as efs
